# International path alias not working

Tags: 6, path-aliases, i18n-l10n

I am trying to translate an existing [site](http://www.hillsongconference.co.uk).

I've used [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) before successfully so I'm not totally new to it. Now to my problem…

I can create content fine in different languages the problem occurs when I try to access languages (other than the default, without path-prefix) with a path-prefix. I keep getting a 404.

[image: URL Aliases]

Example:

- [English](http://hillsongconference.co.uk/home)
- [Swedish](http://hillsongconference.co.uk/se/home)

Their system-path counterparts:

- [English](http://hillsongconference.co.uk/node/1)
- [Swedish](http://hillsongconference.co.uk/node/10)

Any ideas about what might cause this?

*Please note that this is a Drupal 6 install.*

Comment: You are creating seperated nodes, instead of translating them, correct?

Comment: Deleted the node and re-added as a translation just in case.

Comment: Does that help? I was about to post an answer that depends on that solving the problem.

Comment: If you use the "Redirect" module, try to update to the latest dev version or just disable it to see if this probably causes the error?

Comment: @Letharion No it didn't help.

Comment: @Lance I don't use that module. Note that this is a Drupal 6 install not a Drupal 7 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to your fix you posted in language_initialize. It's very strange that the first arg would be empty.

So now that you've added in your changes, http://www.hillsongconference.co.uk/se/home works.
However, this should be exactly the same as http://www.hillsongconference.co.uk/?q=se/home
and you will see that this brings in the 404 error (whereas q=/se/home doesn't).

So I'm worndering if the htaccess file has been edited?  As this is how Drupal converts the arguments in the url path to `$_GET['q']`.  The Drupal .htaccess file also strips out leading slashes, to insure the first argument isn't empty.

You've hacked core now, which is a terrible no-no.  Even if you are never going to update this site, it still needs to be fixed out of principle!

If you are running a nginx setup the correct rewrite (to not include the slash) is  `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1  last;` not `rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1   last;`

Comment: I know amending core is the big no-no I simply did it as a last resort. I never use .htaccess (running a nginx setup here). Brilliant answer! I should have spotted this in the beginning. The config I'm using have been used on many of our sites and only now when attempting multilingual did a problem surface.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in Drupal 6 it is not possible to assign the same alias to two different nodes. When requesting /home the system retrieves the first internal path it encounters (/node/1) in the url alias database table and shows it (works correct for English). However, when requesting /se/home it also retrieves that same internal path (/node/1) and checks if the node's language (en) matches the prefix (se). Because this ain't true, you'll encounter the 404.

I see two possibilities.
1) Change the url alias for swedish home to something else, i.e. "start".

2) Use a view to display the node. Views keep the same url for all languages while you can use a language filter to only show nodes of the current language, i.e. the view at /home shows English nodes while /se/home (as a view) only shows swedish nodes.

Comment: This is correct normally, but not with i18n.  The home page is a multilingual variable, so will be loaded accordingly for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone. I've had to go into core to figure this out. I'm back and I survived the trip.

I found out what is going wrong, no idea how any multi-lingual site works with this bug in it.

> File: [language.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--language.inc/function/language_initialize/6) (function language_initialize)
>
> The problem is this line and the loop beneath it.
>
> `$prefix = array_shift($args);`
>
> Because `$args` is an array of parts made after imploding `$_GET['q']` the first string in that array is always going to be empty let me explain that with a picture:[image: explode()]
>
> That essentially means that the language will never be detected and the path will instead be treated like it's english `"/se/home/"`.
>   Fixed it by adding an extra `$prefix = array_shift($args);` just after it.

Comment: Hmmm... although your explanation makes sense at first glance, I am wondering if you have an error in your path. I would make sure the value of `$_GET['q']` is not `//se/home`.  I think you would get this if you entered `/se/` as path prefix, for example.  I am totally not sure, I am posting on a hunch. It just seems funny a mistake like this would slip by thousands of users.

Comment: @stefgosselin I do think my case is very unique. Not sure what is causing it. I've used i18n without any issues before. The path is actually `/se/home` and I could only solve it this way. I haven't entered anything wrong like that, I would have spotted that before diving into source code. (I even created a new drupal instance on another server just to be sure I didn't mess the basics up.)

Comment: Ok, the path is `/se/home`, is there any way you can have `se/home`?  The only thing I can think of is if you have slashes in the textfield value where you configure the domain prefix. I am curious on this as I use I18N quite a bit and never encoutered this issue, may try to reproduce your issue this weekend if time allows, out of curiosity. Happy coding friend, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I have done this without problems on a Drupal 6 site (for paths created by views). Maybe your problem is the way the language selection is handled.